Compare two fields with Text contains
I have two tables (table1 and table2).
I want to perform an inner merge query with both tables.
I want to check if the parttial name field in table1 is found in table2 may be by using Text.Contains. I am not quite familiar with this.
Any help please please please.

To test if table1.Name is contained within a row of table2.Lookup Value:
in table1, add column ... custom column ... with formula:
= List.AnyTrue(let a=[Name] in List.Transform(Table2[Lookup Value], each Text.Contains(_,a)))


Here is another code if you are looking for column
List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(table2[NameColumn], each Text.Contains(_, [PartialName])))


hi sorry i didn't quite get this one. could you please explain

Hey , the code here, refers to a part of a name or a substring within a name. It is used in scenarios where you want to check if a given substring (partial name) exists

okay. awesome !! thanks a lot

you are most welcome :)
